# Yii : You are not authorized to perform this action issue

Tags: php, yii

I am developing an application for symbian using Yii framework. In my view

```
<?php
    foreach ($simplified_list as $data) {
        echo "<tr>
            <td>" . CHtml::link($data['name'], array('view')) . "</td>
            <td>" . $data['data_volume'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $data['tariff'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $data['tariff_with_vat'] . "</td>
            </tr>";
    }
?>
```

This is the view.php

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id' => 'datapkgview_form',
        'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
    ));
?>

<div class="form">

<div class="row">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
</div>




<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div>
```

And, in my controller here is the action for view.php

```
public function actionView() {



    $this->render('view');
}
```

I get an error as **You are not authorized to perform this action.**

How can I solve this problem.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller file, to to `accessRules()` function and add `*` to users. This means any user can access `view` file.

```
public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Controller File ,the `accessRules()` method contains the following as it can only allow admin but even when i login as admin it showing the same error as

**"You are not authorized to perform this action.**"
The method in the controller is as follows:

```
public function accessRules()
{

    return array(

        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions'=>array('admin','delete','view','index'),
            'users'=>array('admin'),

        ),

    array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```